# Route::has note detecting route resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create links in the top nav menu using the code to check if the route name has a text pattern in it.

All is working except for one route which is also defined as a resource.

Below is my code in the web.php file

```
 Route::get('/bookings', 'BookingController@index')->name('bookings');
 Route::resource('/bookings', 'BookingController');
```

In the app.blade.php file I have the code:

```
@if (Route::has('bookings'))
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('bookings') }}">{{ __('Bookings') }}</a>
  </li>
@endif
```

I checked the routes in php artisan and its listed as existing.

```
| api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | bookings                | bookings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings                | bookings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/create         | bookings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@create                          | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@update                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@show                            | web          |
|        | DELETE    | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@destroy                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/{booking}/edit | bookings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@edit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Route::has('bookings')` checks the route list for a route named `bookings`. While you've got a URL of `bookings`, its **name** in the route list is `bookings.index` - you don't have any route named `bookings`.

(Per your `php artisan route:list` output, your route from the `Route::resource` call is wiping out the earlier `Route::get` call. Remove that redundant/ignored `Route::get` definition.)

`Route::has('bookings.index')` should do the trick (and changing `route('bookings')` to `route('bookings.index')`.

Comment: muchas gracias.